# Less css file include in <head> section

Tags: html, css, less

Which files are needed to include in `<head>` section for less css. At less official site , i have just seen that they have told to include .less and .js file. But it is not working without .css file.

Comment: The JS file converts your less to CSS and inserts this to the DOM. Are you sure, you have added them in the correct order?

Comment: what is your include line in `<head>`!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Referring to LESS documentation (http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage):

Link your .less stylesheets with the rel set to “stylesheet/less”:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Then download less.js from the top of the page, and include it in the `<head>` element of your page, like so:

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.**

This method will cause the less-file act as a regular css-file so no additional files are needed.

This is not a good practice for production environments though. You should compile your less-file to css-file and include it in your `<head>`-section as is without any less- or js-files.

Comment: Running locally on windows 10, trying the above causes this error in Chrome:  `Failed to load file:///C:/Users/my_dir/my-theme.less: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`.

Comment: @user1063287 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

```
@import "styles.less";
```

**OR**

```
@import "styles";
```

its from ur CSS file..
you just need to include it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This one helped me ...

```
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I was tryin to use only this

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```