# LESS files dont't work on dreamweaver CC

Tags: css, ide, less, dreamweaver

Is it possible that LESS files don't work in dreamweaver CC? Because probably my syntaxt is correct, but I don't understand why my style.less file doesn't work, even with simple commands like "color: #ff0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this in `head`: make sure you are using `rel="stylesheet/less"`

```
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
```

and before the `html` closing tag

```
  <script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Source:
[client-side-usage](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage)

Answer (score 0):

if you want include less direct to html file you have to read this topic: [Less css file include in <head> section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335299/less-css-file-include-in-head-section)

or you can convert .less to .css file: http://koala-app.com/ 
or you can use gruntJS: http://gruntjs.com/

Comment: I included in the head section the less and the js files, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's working if I put the entire project inside the "local server folder" (xampp in this case) even if I  'm using only simple html tag, .js and .less file. No php, mysql and others.

Could you tell me why of this behaviour?